How to delete email from a child folder and not the parent folder using ms-graph in C#
Was wondering if anyone can help me. Using MS-Graph and C# I am trying to delete a mail item from a subfolder under the INBOX but its always deleting that item from the INBOX. This is a blocking issue for me at the moment
Heres my delete statement, I have tried both statements below but its still deleting the mail item in the INBOX
await _graphServiceClient.Users[senderAddress].MailFolders[archiveFolder.Id].Messages[msgs[0].Id].Request().DeleteAsync();

OR
await _graphServiceClient.Users[senderAddress].MailFolders.Inbox.ChildFolders[archiveFolder.Id].Messages[msgs[0].Id].Request().DeleteAsync();



mailboxAddress=email address
archiveFolder.Id = is the subfolder's id


what is msgs[0].id  are you passing in an array of messages? or are you just trying to delete the first message in the folder?

double check whether you send the correct message id

Yes, message id was incorrect....ty
